# ImageRestyle not working in docs?

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

`ImageRestyle[]` seems like a cool new function in v11.2, but is there something I need to to get this to work:

[image]

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB.

**Update**

The suggestion in the comment was to download a certain NetModel, which seems to fail:

[image]

The ResourceObject seems to exist but won't load:

[image]

Comment: What's your system? yode was having issues with this too. It works fine on my old, GPU-less mac.

Comment: `ImageRestyle` works for me on Windows 7 x64 with version 11.2.0. Probably the best is to follow the recommendation from the error message and contact Wolfram.

Comment: Actually it works,but you have to re-run it some times..

Comment: @yode it never works for me

Comment: Also works in Win 8.1 Pro with Mma 11.2.0

Comment: I had the same problem on Win 10. The problem was solved when I downloaded the network for fast restyling manually. `NetModel["AdaIN-Style Trained on MS-COCO and Painter by Numbers Data"]`

Comment: Running NetModel["AdaIN-Style Trained on MS-COCO and Painter by Numbers Data"] gives $Failed @AlexeyGolyshev

Comment: What does Internal`$LastInternalFailure say?

Comment: @StefanR See my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible the downloaded copy you have is somehow corrupted. You can wipe it out with:

```
ResourceRemove[ResourceObject["AdaIN-Style Trained on MS-COCO and Painter by 
Numbers Data"]]
```

And then `Quit` and try again.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do this without a `Quit`?

Comment: Running your code gave these warnings: ResourceAcquire::apierr: The specified resource could not be found; ResourceRemove::unkro: The specified resource $Failed is not cached locally.

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: That's odd since `ResourceObject[style]` in your code found the resource.
If that is still the case (In[67] still gives the same Out[67]), You can use `ResourceRemove[style]`.

Comment: @BobSandheinrich Thanks, it's working now.